# Passing structure in a function

Tags: c, function, structure

The following code is giving errors when compiling:

```
int add_employee(struct emp e)
     {
        printf("%i\n", e.emp_no);
        printf("Date of Birth:\n");
        printf("%i / %i / %i\n", e.birth_date.dd, e.birth_date.mm, e.birth_date.yyyy);
        printf("%s %s\n", e.first_name, e.last_name);
        printf("%s\n", e.gender);
        printf("Date of Hirting:\n");
        printf("%i / %i / %i\n", e.hire_date.dd, e.hire_date.mm, e.hire_date.yyyy);
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        struct employees emp, *ptr;
        ptr = &emp;
        int i=0;
        ptr->emp_no = get_int("Employee No.: ");
        printf("Date of Birth:\n");
        ptr->birth_date.dd = get_int("Date: ");
        ptr->birth_date.mm = get_int("Month: ");
        ptr->birth_date.yyyy = get_int("Year: ");
        ptr->first_name = get_string("First Name: ");
        ptr->last_name = get_string("Last Name: ");
        ptr->gender = get_string("Gender(M/F): ");
       printf("Date of Hiring:\n");
       ptr->hire_date.dd = get_int("Date: ");
       ptr->hire_date.mm = get_int("Month: ");
       ptr->hire_date.yyyy = get_int("Year: ");
      i = add_employee(emp);
       if(i == 0)
       {
           printf("Employee added successfully\n");
       }
```

Following is the error when I compile it using clang:

```
app.c:75:25: warning: declaration of 'struct emp' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
int add_employee(struct emp e)
                        ^
app.c:75:29: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct emp'
int add_employee(struct emp e)
                            ^
app.c:75:25: note: forward declaration of 'struct emp'
int add_employee(struct emp e)
                        ^
app.c:104:22: error: argument type 'struct emp' is incomplete
    i = add_employee(emp);
                     ^~~
app.c:75:25: note: forward declaration of 'struct emp'
int add_employee(struct emp e)
                        ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Where is `struct emp` definition? That is what compiler is worrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the line in `main`

```
struct employees emp, *ptr;
```

It seems the type is `struct employees`.

So function should be

```
int add_employee(struct employees e)
```